# Moq : Mocking GetbyId repository method returning null

Tags: nunit, moq, repository-pattern

I am using Moq and I have a repository that I am trying to create mock methods.
The GetAll method returns the values however the GetById returns null.

```
var currencyRepo = new Mock<ICurrencyRepository>();
var currencies =  new List<Currency>{new Currency
                                      {
                                          CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                          CurrencyId = 1,
                                      }, 
                                      new Currency
                                             {
                                                  CurrencyCode = "EUR",
                                                  CurrencyId = 2
                                             }};

currencyRepo.Setup(c => c.GetAll()).Returns(currencies);
currencyRepo.Setup(c => c.GetById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns((int i) =>  currencies.Single(c => c.CurrencyId == i));

var currency = currencyRepo.Object.GetById(1); //This always returns null
//currency is always null
//but calling the GetAll method works!


var currencyList = currencyRepo.Object.GetAll(); //this works!
```

any ideas?

Comment: I solved it change to long in setup method because the GetById accepts a long parameter. DUH!

Comment: Consider adding an answer to your own question, this may help future visitors to this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it change to long in setup method because the GetById accepts a long parameter. DUH!